# Plotting multiple groups from a dataframe with datashader as lines

Tags: python, pandas, datashader

I am trying to make plots with datashader. the data itself is a time series of points in polar coordiantes. i managed to transform them to cartesian coordianted(to have equal spaced pixles) and i can plot them with datashader.

the point where i am stuck is that if i just plot them with `line()` instead of `points()` it just connects the whole dataframe as a single  line. i would like to plot the data of the dataframe group per group(the groups are the names in `list_of_names` ) onto the canvas as lines.

data can be found [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/9dbd6e7a)

[image: i get this kind of image with datashader]

i get this kind of image with datashader

[image: This is a zoomed in view of the plot generated with points```´ instead of line()```` the goal is to produce the same plot but with connected lines instead of points]

This is a zoomed in view of the plot generated with `points()` instead of `line()` the goal is to produce the same plot but with connected lines instead of points

```
import datashader as ds, pandas as pd, colorcet
import numby as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')


print(df)

starlink_name = df.loc[:,'Name']
starlink_alt = df.loc[:,'starlink_alt']
starlink_az = df.loc[:,'starlink_az']

name = starlink_name.values
alt = starlink_alt.values
az = starlink_az.values
print(name)
print(df['Name'].nunique())
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

for name, df_name in df.groupby('Name'):
    print(name)

df_grouped = df.groupby('Name')



list_of_names = list(df_grouped.groups)
print(len(list_of_names))
#########################################################################################

#i want this kind of plot with connected lines with datashader

#########################################################################################
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], polar=True)
# ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_rlim(90, 60, 1)
# Note: you must set the end of arange to be slightly larger than 90 or it won't include 90
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 91, 15))
ax.set_rlim(bottom=90, top=0)


for name in list_of_names:
    df2 = df_grouped.get_group(name)
    ax.plot(np.deg2rad(df2['starlink_az']), df2['starlink_alt'], linestyle='solid', marker='.',linewidth=0.5, markersize=0.1)
plt.show()


print(df)
#########################################################################################

#transformation to cartasian coordiantes

#########################################################################################
df['starlink_alt'] = 90 -  df['starlink_alt']

df['x'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.deg2rad(row.starlink_alt) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(row.starlink_az)), axis=1)
df['y'] = df.apply(lambda row: -1 * np.deg2rad(row.starlink_alt) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(row.starlink_az)), axis=1)

#########################################################################################

# this is what i want but as lines group per group

#########################################################################################

cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=2000, plot_height=2000)
agg = cvs.points(df, 'y', 'x')
img = ds.tf.shade(agg, cmap=colorcet.fire, how='eq_hist')


#########################################################################################

#here i am stuck

#########################################################################################


for name in list_of_names:
    df2 = df_grouped.get_group(name)
    cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=2000, plot_height=2000)
    agg = cvs.line(df2, 'y', 'x')
    img = ds.tf.shade(agg, cmap=colorcet.fire, how='eq_hist')
    #plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you have a couple options. One is inserting NaN rows as a breakpoint into your dataframe when using [`cvs.line`](https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/blob/master/datashader/core.py#L216). You need DataShader to "pick up the pen" as it were, by inserting a row of NaNs after each group. It's not the slickest, but that's a current recommended solution.

Really simple, hacky example:

```py
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'name': list('AABBCCDD'),
    ...:     'x': np.arange(8),
    ...:     'y': np.arange(10, 18),
    ...: })

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
  name  x   y
0    A  0  10
1    A  1  11
2    B  2  12
3    B  3  13
4    C  4  14
5    C  5  15
6    D  6  16
7    D  7  17
```

This block groups on the 'name' column, then reindexes each group to be one element longer than the original data:

```py
In [20]: res = df.set_index('name').groupby('name').apply(
    ...:     lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(np.arange(len(x) + 1))
    ...: )

In [21]: res
Out[21]:
          x     y
name
A    0  0.0  10.0
     1  1.0  11.0
     2  NaN   NaN
B    0  2.0  12.0
     1  3.0  13.0
     2  NaN   NaN
C    0  4.0  14.0
     1  5.0  15.0
     2  NaN   NaN
D    0  6.0  16.0
     1  7.0  17.0
     2  NaN   NaN
```

You can plug this reindexed dataframe into datashader to have multiple disconnected lines in the result.

This is a still-open issue on the datashader repo, including additional examples and boilerplate code: https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/issues/257

Other options include restructuring your data to accommodate one of cvs.line's other formats. From the [`Canvas.line` docstring](https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/blob/master/datashader/core.py#L216):

```py
def line(self, source, x=None, y=None, agg=None, axis=0, geometry=None,
         antialias=False):
    Parameters
    ----------
    source : pandas.DataFrame, dask.DataFrame, or xarray.DataArray/Dataset
        The input datasource.
    x, y : str or number or list or tuple or np.ndarray
        Specification of the x and y coordinates of each vertex
        * str or number: Column labels in source
        * list or tuple: List or tuple of column labels in source
        * np.ndarray: When axis=1, a literal array of the
          coordinates to be used for every row
    agg : Reduction, optional
        Reduction to compute. Default is ``any()``.
    axis : 0 or 1, default 0
        Axis in source to draw lines along
        * 0: Draw lines using data from the specified columns across
             all rows in source
        * 1: Draw one line per row in source using data from the
             specified columns
```

There are a number of additional examples in the cvs.line docstring. You can pass arrays as the x, y arguments giving multiple columns to use in forming lines when `axis=1`, or you can a dataframe with ragged array values.

See this [pull request adding the line options](https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/pull/694) (h/t to @James-a-bednar in the comments) for a discussion of their use.

Comment: works perfectly!

Comment: The Datashader docs don't necessarily explain all the ways you can separate the lines, but there's an overview at https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/pull/694 ; NaN separators are probably the best way in this case, but you can make a row per line, column per line, or use a ragged data structure as well; whatever's convenient!

Comment: Oh nice - thanks for weighing in on this @JamesA.Bednar! I'll update the answer